# Query Builder using the like operator and dynamic values

Tags: cakephp-3.0, query-builder

CakePHP Version 3.5.5

**What I've got:**

I've got search functionality on my index pages which allows a user to search by column and value. The user selects the column from a select list and adds text into an input. I pick up this data with the following which works:

```
$query = $Users->find()
     ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
         return $exp->like($this->request->getData('column'), $this->request->getData('input') . '%');
     })
     ->andWhere([
         'status' => $filter,
         'cid_1' => $c1
     ]);
```

When using the debugKit it reveals the sql as: (Extract only to help explain)

FROM users Users WHERE (role LIKE :c0 AND status = :c1 AND cid_1 = :c2)',

**What I'm trying to do is the following:**

```
$testColumn = $this->request->getData('column');          
$testInput = $this->request->getData('input');

$query = $Users->find()
    ->where(function ($exp, $q) {                    
        return $exp->like($testColumn, $testInput . '%');
    })
    ->andWhere([
        'status' => $filter,
        'cid_1' => $c1
    ]);
```

The $testColumn variable is undefined.

Whe using the debugKit it reveals the sql as: (Extract only to help explain)

FROM users Users WHERE ( LIKE :c0 AND status = :c1 AND cid_1 = :c2)',

IE: The role is not being declared before the LIKE.

**What I've tried:**

**1.** return $exp->like("$testColumn", "$testInput" . '%');

Result: Exactly the same - Variable is still undefined.

DebugKit: FROM users Users WHERE ( LIKE :c0 AND status = :c1 AND cid_1 = :c2)',

**2.** return $exp->like("'$testColumn'", "'$testInput'" . '%');

Result: It added '' before LIKE as can be seen below but I still can't get that variable defined.

DebugKit: FROM users Users WHERE ('' LIKE :c0 AND status = :c1 AND cid_1 = :c2)',

**My Question:**

Is there a way to use a dynamic value to select the search data.

**Update:**

Is it that I can't assign getData to a variable in this context.

**You can't do this:**

$testColumn = $this->request->getData('column');
return $exp->like($testColumn, $testInput . '%');

**But you can do this:**

```
$testColumn = $this->request->getData('column');
echo 'testColumn is ' . $testColumn . '<br />';

if ($testColumn === 'role') {
    echo 'in column passed ' . '<br />';   
}
else {
    echo 'in column failed ' . '<br />';   
}
```

Thanks. Z.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Alimon Karim as requested.

I'm using post and my url is: https://localhost/app/users/search

Thanks Alimon, it works.

Comment: are you sending data by get method or post ? After click on search button what is your URL is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
->where(function ($exp, $q) {
```

with

```
->where(function ($exp, $q) use ($testColumn,$testInput) {
```